# Regex not working, at least in command line

Tags: regex, perl, cmd

I have a regex:

`($value) = $line =~  /\ABC(.+?)\#/;`

For input, e.g.:

(32321213321) ABC 24432.232 #Junk

Which is meant to catch the number between FD and #.

When I run it through the command line, it returns a space. Through Padre, it returns a space + the number before `#`.

Is there something wrong with the regex?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you escape the `A`? I can understand that some people redundantly escape punctuation because they are not sure which need to be escaped, but never seen anyone escape a letter before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your regex, you have escaped the `A`. This then becomes an escape sequence, [an assertion](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Assertions) `\A` to match the beginning of the string. Another version of the same escape is `^` . And your string does not start there, so the regex cannot match. You have another redundant escape as well, before `#`. The regex you need is

```
/ABC(.+?)#/
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better as `/ABC (.+?) #/`, to isolate the number without any spaces on it?

Comment: @Lomky That would be for the OP to decide.

Comment: I've been using this regex and running it out of Padre for a month now without a problem. When I try to run it from the command line, though, it doesn't work. Your solution did clear up that problem.

Comment: @user2795733 Technically speaking, that is impossible, unless Padre somehow changed the regex. A possibility is perhaps that you were using `\bABC`, or some other valid escape sequence.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
$line =~  /ABC *([0-9 ]+?) *#/;
```

OR better:

```
$line =~  /ABC *(\d+(?: \d+)*) *#/;
```